# Wordpress show taxonomy with acf

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't get the name of the taxonomy using acf (select Multiple) in WordPress.

```
$categories_user = get_field('product__services', $company_id);
```

When I `var_dump($categories_user)` it outputs:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#3816 (10) { 
        ["term_id"]=> int(28) 
        ["name"]=> string(17) "sous category 2-4" 
        ["slug"]=> string(17) "sous-category-2-4" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(28) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "project_cat" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(25) 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3818 (10) { 
        ["term_id"]=> int(34) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Ywz categorie" 
        ["slug"]=> string(13) "ywz-categorie" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(34) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "project_cat" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(0) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about your problem so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the data...you just need to display it using a standard `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( $categories_user as $cat ) {
    echo $cat->name;
}
```